# How to transform the input of a jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

i'm hardly trying to transform the input value of a jquery datepicker. it should display the value in the forma dd.mm.yy but for my database i need to store the date as mm/dd/yy

i tried it like here [1]:

```
//using the jquery UI datepicker
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

//transforming the val() of datepicker  
$("#button").click(function() {    
    var dateTranfs = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' }).val();
    console.log (dateTranfs);    
});
```

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/zBsz2/9/

Comment: Whar server side language are you using to store data in DB? You could easily convert it server side...

Comment: isn't mm/dd/yy the default format value of the datepicker??

Comment: i use php to write the data in an mysql db

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do.

```
console.log ($.datepicker.formatDate("dd.mm.yy", $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate")));
```

Comment: you can `format` the `date` as per your requirement before sending it to `DB`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zBsz2/16/

you have to set the format like:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

Edit: Do you want it to transfer it via POST/GET in a form? I updated my fiddle maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: this changes the way, the date is displayed. that's not what i wantd ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want year in 2 digits you need to specify date format as `$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y'});` refer [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Datepicker/formatDate&redirect=no) and your working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zBsz2/19/)

Comment: this changes the way, the date is displayed. that's not what i want ;)

Comment: @juleee: then can you pls tell what do you want exactly?

Comment: "it should display the value in the format dd.mm.yy but for my database i need to store the date as mm/dd/yy"

Comment: that's exactly what i want. although i don't understand why jquery doesn't offer something like this,

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
//using the jquery UI datepicker
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });
});

//transforming the val() of datepicker  
$("#button").click(function() {    
    var date = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var dateTranfs = (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '/' + y;
    console.log (dateTranfs.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have updated your code like this

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
});

//transforming the val() of datepicker  
$("#button").click(function() {    
  var dateTranfs = $('#datepicker').val();

  console.log (dateTranfs);    
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: this helps. but i have to add +1 to dateTranfs.getMonth()

isn't there some "ready to use function in the jquery api?

Answer (score 0):

The `getDate` method of datepicker returns a date type, not a string.

You need to format the returned value to a string using your date format. Use datepicker's formatDate function:

```
var dateTypeVar = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dateTypeVar);
```